# it's possible send a streaming video from Youtube using cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, youtube, youtube-data-api

I want show a live video streaming from youtube using cordova, but I no sure if it's possible or not.
I readed about `youtube.liveBroadcasts.bind` bind from Youtube API, but I'm not sure if it's possible using cordova. 
exist a way to take this streaming with cordova?